# C: Unable to store lines from a file into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgets

This is some code I used to read and store lines from a text file into an "expressions" array:

```
//create array for going through the file
char lines[128];
//create array for storing expressions
char **expressions = malloc(128*sizeof(char*));

FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
int count = 0;
while (fgets(lines,128,file)){
    expressions[count] = lines;
    printf("expressions[%d] is %s\n",count,expressions[count]);
    count++;
}

for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
    printf("%s",expressions[i]);
}
```

And this is the text this code is trying to read:

```
f = g + h - 42;
g = 12 + 23;
```

My issue here is that while it appears to go through the file properly (count matches the number of lines), the final print loop prints the last line `g = 12 + 23` twice instead of the two distinct lines. Why is this occuring and what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you read a line, you store it in the `lines` character array, and then you save the address of that array in the next space of `expressions`. If you look at the values stored in `expressions` you'll find that they are all the same.

If you want to keep a copy of each line, you're going to have to have space to store a copy of each line. If you have a maximum number of lines which you're going to deal with, you can allocate that memory in the program. Otherwise you're going to have to start using dynamic memory allocation.

Let's work on 100 lines maximum, with each line no longer than 127 characters (as above):

```
char expressions[100][128];

int count = 0;
while (fgets(lines,128,file)) {
    strcpy(expressions[count], lines);
    printf("expressions[%d] is %s\n",count,expressions[count]);
    count++;

    if (count == 100)
      break;
}
```

Comment: This ended up working for me, thank you; so since my buffer array was being overwritten each time by fgets, the solution was to copy my current line to the count index rather than use an assignment operator?

Comment: Ace. Glad it's working! Yes, as you say, you're saving a copy of what you've read so that you can overwrite it next time. Of course, there's other ways of doing it, like using `fgets()` to write directly into each successive index of `expressions` but I'll leave you to explore that if you want to.

Comment: And if you'd like to accept the answer, that would be great too!